# Problems getting Sass Compass project working in CodeKit

Tags: sass, codekit, compass

First off, I love CodeKit.

But I have no idea how to resolve the issue I'm facing right now and was hoping someone else might have knowledge to resolve.

I created a new project based on the HTML5 Boilerplate CodeKit project https://github.com/jrodl3r/h5bp-codekit

But when I try to compile using Compass, I receive the following error:

```
Compass failed to run because your Mac has an older version of Sass and/or Compass 
installed that conflicts with the newer versions in CodeKit. You must remove 
all versions of Sass below 3.3.rc6 and all versions of Compass below 1.0.alpha18. 
Do this at the command line by running 'sudo gem uninstall sass' and 'sudo gem 
uninstall compass'.
```

However, my versions of Sass and Compass are up-to-date:

[image]

I've tried:

- Uninstalling Sass & Compass and reinstalling it
- Uninstalling Sass & COmpass and installing the version mentioned in the error
- Cleaning the project and compiling

Not really quite sure where to begin.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've checked for certain that there are no old versions of the gems still kicking around after you remove them?  http://guides.rubygems.org/rubygems-basics/

Comment: Yup, didn't mention that. When I first ran "$ gem uninstall sass" in the command line, I found a couple other versions available. In which I removed. I thought that must have been it, but I still run into issues after that.